# ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21) additional info: objectClass: value #3 invalid per syntax

Tags: ldap, openldap, postfix-mta

I have the ldif

```
dn: uniqueIdentifier=user.acc,ou=people,dc=domaine,dc=com    
objectClass: organizationalPerson    
objectClass: person    
objectClass: top    
objectClass: PostfixBookMailAccount    
objectClass: extensibleObject    
objectClass: inetOrgPerson    
objectClass: posixAccount    
objectClass: shadowAccount    
uid: user.acc    
cn: user acc    
givenName: acc    
uidNumber: 2000    
gidNumber: 5002    
loginShell: /bin/bash    
homeDirectory: /home/user    
mail: user.acc@domaine.com    
mailEnabled: TRUE    
mailGidNumber: 5000
```

which i'm trying to use to configure the ldap server with the following command :

```
ldapadd -W -D "cn=admin,dc=domaine,dc=com" -f userimport.ldif
```

it gives me the error

```
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #3 invalid per syntax
```

here is the configuration i used

```
 cd /etc/ldap/schema
 wget http://www.postfix-buch.com/download/postfix-book.schema.gze
 gunzip postfix-book.schema.gz
 cd /etc/ldap/schema
 mkdir ldif_output
 touch schema_convert.conf
```

The schema_convert.conf file contains the schema to be converted (and any dependencies):

```
include /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/postfix-book.schema
```

Finally, in the postfix-book.ldif, the following changes need to be made:

```
dn: cn=postfix-book,cn=schema,cn=config
cn: postfix-book
```

Remove the metadata starting from structuralObjectClass
Then add it to the directory as follows:

```
sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f postfix-book.ldif
```

the file postfix-book.ldif contains the schema of PostfixBookMAilAccount:

```
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.2.2.1
  NAME 'PostfixBookMailAccount'
  DESC 'Mail account used in Postfix Book'
  SUP top AUXILIARY
  MUST mail
  MAY ( mailHomeDirectory $ mailAlias $ mailGroupMember $ mailUidNumber $ mailGidNumber $ mailEnabled $ mailQuota $ mailStorageDirectory ) )
```

here is the file postfix-book.schema

```
enter code here
# $Id$
#
# State of Mind
# Private Enterprise Number: 29426
#
# OID prefix: 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426
#
# Attributes: 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.10.x
#


attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.10.1 NAME 'mailHomeDirectory'
DESC 'The absolute path to the mail user home directory'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.10.2 NAME 'mailAlias'
    DESC 'RFC822 Mailbox - mail alias'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreIA5SubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{256} )

 attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.10.3 NAME 'mailUidNumber'
    DESC 'UID required to access the mailbox'
    EQUALITY integerMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )

 attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.10.4 NAME 'mailGidNumber'
    DESC 'GID required to access the mailbox'
    EQUALITY integerMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )

  attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.10.5 NAME 'mailEnabled'
  DESC 'TRUE to enable, FALSE to disable account'
    EQUALITY booleanMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.7 SINGLE-VALUE )

 attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.10.6 NAME 'mailGroupMember'
 DESC 'Name of a mail distribution list'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.10.7 NAME 'mailQuota'
DESC 'Mail quota limit in kilobytes'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.10.8 NAME 'mailStorageDirectory'
DESC 'The absolute path to the mail users mailbox'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )


 #
 # Objects: 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.2.2.x
 #

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.2.2.1 NAME 'PostfixBookMailAccount'
    SUP top AUXILIARY
DESC 'Mail account used in Postfix Book'
MUST ( mail )
    MAY ( mailHomeDirectory $ mailAlias $ mailGroupMember 
    $ mailUidNumber $ mailGidNumber $ mailEnabled
    $ mailQuota $mailStorageDirectory ) )

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.29426.1.2.2.2 NAME 'PostfixBookMailForward'
    SUP top AUXILIARY
DESC 'Mail forward used in Postfix Book'
MUST ( mail $ mailAlias ))
```

and thank you for your help

Comment: Refer : http://serverfault.com/questions/691750/what-does-the-ldapadd-error-additional-info-objectclass-value-3-invalid-per

Comment: @Roshith first thank you for your answer , but i had already seen this question , we don't have the same problem , for my case the problem is with  : objectClass: PostfixBookMailAccount   , and i don't know what should i do ..

Comment: Following up on @Roshith's comment, if you dump the config, do you see the schema definition for `PostfixBookMailAccount`?

Comment: @rlandster i added the configuration above , thank you for you answer

Comment: You added the configuration but you didn't  answer the question. Is a definition for PostfixBookMailAccount present in the schemas you have loaded?

Comment: @EJP : sorry , i have added the file postfix-book.schema , i hope that you are talking about that file , if it's not the case , can you please tell me which file should i add here?